# Correctly describe a function when its codomain is a set of functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I saw the following way of describing a function $f: A \rightarrow B$, defined as $f(a) = a$. How to correctly define a function when its codomain is supposed to be a set of functions?

For example, I need to define a function $g: N \rightarrow N^N$ to prove that it's injective. I'm thinking of two ways of defining this function:

1. Let $g: N \rightarrow N^N$, defined as $g(n) = f(k) = n$, where $f: N \rightarrow N$.
2. Let $f_i: N \rightarrow N$, defined as $f_i(n) = i$ for any $i \in N$. Then $g(n) = f_n$

Could someone please explain if there's something wrong with my definitions? The first way seems to be incorrect or at least confusing, because $f(k)$ looks like a result of $f(k)$ for some $k$. So I'm especially worrying about the second way. Is it correct to define something with subscript and use that subscript as if it is something real (like an argument of the function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version, taken literally as written, makes no sense. Your second is much better, but it can be improved:

> For each $i\in\Bbb N$ let $f_i:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N:n\mapsto i$, and let $g:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}:n\mapsto f_n$.

Or if you prefer a little more verbiage:

> For each $i\in\Bbb N$ let $f_i:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ be the constant function $f_i(n)=i$, and define $g:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ by letting $g(n)=f_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot!

Comment: @E.Shcherbo: You’re very welcome!